# Get the containers with inputs and their values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get a DOM container (entire HTML code inside it), inside it has some input texts. When I save this DOM in the database the input values are not there.

I have tried:

```
$(".container").html()
$(".container").prop('outerHTML')
$(".container").text()
$(".container").get(0).outerHTML
```

Example:

As it is in the database now:

```
<div class="container stackExemple">
    <input type="text" name="1">
    <input type="text" name="2">
    <input type="text" name="3">
    <input type="text" name="4">
</div>
```

As i need it to be:

```
<div class="container stackExemple">
    <input type="text" name="1" value="value1">
    <input type="text" name="2" value="value2">
    <input type="text" name="3" value="value3">
    <input type="text" name="4" value="value4">
</div>
```

Comment: How you are storing in database? What back-end language you are using for back-end?

Comment: `$(".container").html()` is give you html inside class `container`

Comment: just to be sure, do you actually have the `value=""` part in your HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the *value* attribute using [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```js
$(".container [type=text]").each(function(i){
  $(this).attr('value', 'value'+(i+1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container stackExemple">
    <input type="text" name="1">
    <input type="text" name="2">
    <input type="text" name="3">
    <input type="text" name="4">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Updating the html attribute `value` will update the value of the input, but updating the the value of the input, will not update the html attribute.
The trick is to update the `value` attribute of the elements before you read the html.

```js
$("#print").on("click", function() {
  $("#results").text(JSON.stringify(getContainer(), (key, value) => (!key || !isNaN(key)) ? value : undefined, 4).replace(/\\n/g, "\n").replace(/\\"/g, "'"));
});

function getContainer() {
  return $(".container").map(function() {
    $("input", this).each(function() {
      this.setAttribute("value", this.value);
    });
    return this.outerHTML;
  });
}
```

```css
#results {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container stackExemple">
  <input type="text" name="1">
  <input type="text" name="2">
  <input type="text" name="3">
  <input type="text" name="4">
</div>

<div class="container stackExemple">
  <input type="text" name="5">
  <input type="text" name="6">
  <input type="text" name="7">
  <input type="text" name="8">
</div>

<button id="print">Print</button>
<code id="results"></code>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about writing the `val()` back as a `value` attribute on demand?

```js
$('#test').on('click',function(){

  var $container = $('.container');

  $('input',$container).each(function(){
      $(this).attr('value',$(this).val());

  });

  console.log($container.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container stackExemple">
    <input type="text" name="1">
    <input type="text" name="2">
    <input type="text" name="3">
    <input type="text" name="4">
</div>

<button id="test">Click for html</button>
```